# Align a TableViewer and TreeViewer

Tags: java, tree, swt, jface, tableviewer

I am creating an SWT application with two `TreeViewers` and a `TableViewer` in between them.

The `TableViewer` contains images in each row that indicate something about the date in that row of the `TreeViewer`.

However the problem is that the images in the `TableViewer` are not properly aligning with the rows in the `TreeViewer`. Is there any way for me to ensure that their rows stay exactly leveld?

Thanks

**ADDED**

[image: Non aligning TreeViewer and TableViewer]

Comment: I can't really share what the project looks like. Just imagine a TreeViewer, then a table with a small icon in each row, then another Treeviewer. The table rows aren't aligning perfectly with the TreeViewer rows.

Comment: Well, it's really hard to tell what's going on without you sharing some code or visual feedback...

Comment: @Baz ok I added a simple example

Comment: I'll have a look tomorrow. You can remove the content if it's confidential...

Comment: @Baz It's alright, nothing top secret in this shot. THanks though. Can you took a look quickly at another Q I just asked before signing off?

Comment: Already had a look. No idea, sorry.

Comment: Do they align without the image in the `TableViewer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the way the height of a row is measured by overriding the behaviour of the "measuring method", i.e. adding a `Listener` to `SWT.MeasureItem`. There is a good example [here](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-CustomDrawingTableAndTreeItems/index.html). Just use the height of the icon you use in the `TreeViewer` plus maybe a couple of border pixels.

Here is the important code part:

```
Display display = new Display();
Shell shell = new Shell(display);
shell.setBounds(10,10,200,250);
final Table table = new Table(shell, SWT.NONE);
table.setBounds(10,10,150,200);
table.setLinesVisible(true);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE).setText("item " + i);
}
table.addListener(SWT.MeasureItem, new Listener() {
   public void handleEvent(Event event) {
      int clientWidth = table.getClientArea().width;
      event.height = event.gc.getFontMetrics().getHeight() * 2;
      event.width = clientWidth * 2;
   }
});
shell.open();
while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
   if (!display.readAndDispatch()) display.sleep();
}
display.dispose();
```